# Части речи. Частица

Tags: части-речи, частица

Слово "обычно" может быть частицей?

Comment: Словарь говорит, что ОБЫЧНО — наречие. Приведите примеры, в которых может показаться, что ОБЫЧНО - частица.

Answer (score 1):

Может ли слово *обычно* быть частицей? В принципе можно зайти на сайт Грамота.ру и увидеть в приведенном там толковом словаре, что **нет, не может.**

Это наречие  с двумя знчениями:

ОБЫЧНО, нареч. 1. к Обычный. Жизнь идёт о., своим чередом. 2. Постоянно, как правило, большей частью. Днём он о. спит.

Но вот почему функция частицы для этого слова невозможна? Ведь в нем есть оценочное значение, которое свойственно модальному классу слов, выражающих отношение говорящего: обычно, как правило. Тем не менее наречие *обычно* к частицам не относят. **И вопрос**:  а можно ли без словаря ответить на заданный вопрос?

**Грамматическая справка**

***Частицы*** — сложный класс, туда входят слова с различным значением и разными функциями, поэтому нужно знать классификацию частиц: указательные, определительные, усилительные, модальные, эмоционально-экспрессивные и т.д.

Нас может заинтересовать класс определительных частиц, близких по структуре к слову *обычно*: просто, прямо, точно и др., которые имеют оценочное значение.

Например, слово *просто* может быть обстоятельством и частицей: Задача решается просто (обстоятельство).  Он просто смеется над тобой (частица).

Но наречие ***обычно*** сходно по значению не с частицами, а с вводными словами: *как обычно*, *как всегда*, *как правило* (выражение степени обычности), но в этом случае необходимым элементом является союз ***как***.

***Как обычно*** может быть вводным словом и наречием в роли обстоятельств:

В то утро мы все как обычно собрались за завтраком в большой столовой. Однако жизнь, как обычно, превосходила все ожидания.

Comment: Jasmin, я объясню поправки: выделение Жирным — особенно рассредотачивающий фактор и враг вдумчивого чтения.Два-три слова на хороший абзац уже достаточно. Такое выделение (особенно на этом сайте в этом редакторе) ещё и чрезмерно контрастно к основной толщине букв и особенно знаков, которые вообще-то не должны утолщаться, если фраза не выделена целиком (это место я не поправил).

Comment: В этом очень информативном и полезном ответе мне не хватает одного простого предложения с прямым ответом на заданный вопрос: "Слово *обычно* не является  частицей никогда."